# Why is it hard to do a task while actually you can do it?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, developmental-psychology

I would start it with a word "Laziness". I actually have realized that every task will not finish if I do not start do it, and I always trigger my motivation by thinking there will be big consequence if I keep postpone it. But, what is wrong with me? every time I start to do my task (assignments) I am getting sleepy, bored, and in few minutes I would grab my phone to chit chat with people or watching YouTube. I have tried to avoid my phone by asking my friend to hide it from me, but it did not work much, I just watched movie in my laptop. Come on, I cant ask my friend to hide my laptop too, my assignments are there.

It was happening for 6 years, and I just can not accept it. Actually, The assignment is not out of my ability, sometime I could do my assignments in few hours for several days, but without any reason I lost that spirit again. What is wrong? how can I deal with it? and why it happens on me while some other people could just control their self easily? is there any scientific explanation for this?

It perhaps the most stupid wrong placed question you have ever found, but I need your help, indeed. If you ever experience the similar thing, please share.. Thank you